# How to change the constructor parameter in magento2?

Tags: magento2, di, magento2.4.2

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entity,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $event,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entity, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $event, $store, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
```

I want to change the parameter of the constructor. This module is installed by the composer and while compiling the code I am getting the issue

**Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; File:**

So I am adding another module in the app/code/ directory and passing these argument to solve the issue

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entity,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $event,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::class,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entity, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $event, $store, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
```

I am using preference to override the same file. Actually When I am passing the dependency in the core module then it is working fine but I don't want to make any changes in this module.
then How can I replace these arguments using a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the parameters by dependency injection

However, this is a rather difficult way that requires you to know the basics of Magento.

You can refer to this document to better understand the method I have given you: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/215

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `di.xml` file.

I don't know which class you are trying to change the constructor for, but you'd take that class, say `Magento\Some\Class`, and use that as the `type` below.

You'll then define the argument names and values that you'd like to pass in. It appears that the last three arguments are what you would like to change.

Rather than using a class preference, it's a much better idea to use `di.xml` here with argument substitution:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Some\Class">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document::class</argument>
            <argument name="connection" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface</argument>
            <argument name="resource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```